# Azure backup server

Tags: azure, backup

I have been having trouble finding specific answers to my questions about Azure Backup Server.  Basically, I have a client with a Hyper-V Host and two guests.  All are running Server 2019.  Does Azure Backup Server provide the mechanism to easily restore and spin up these servers in the Azure cloud for quarterly testing, or will I need to create an Azure cloud host to perform this testing?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restore a backup of a Hyper-V VM, stored in Azure, to Azure as an Azure VM. Because currently this is not a supported scenario. You can only restore to an on-premises host.
FAQ reference URL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-dpm-azure-server-faq#can-i-restore-a-backup-of-a-hyper-v-or-vmware-vm-stored-in-azure-to-azure-as-an-azure-vm